# Help with adding OR logic/condition to my onClick JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with multiple Validation cases when value is Yes or No:
Here are the two conditions I'm trying to validate:

[image]

[image]

Here is what I have for the first condition (which works) but I need to allow for both conditions:

```
    `else if(objQuote.records.CAA_Agreement__c === null && objQuote.records.SYS_Account_Credit_Application__c !== 'No') 
{ 
alert("No CAA found! You have to attach the CAA Agreement to the Quote before you can create the BSO."); 
}`
```

Here are the field/value types:
[image]

Comment: What is CAA Agreement (string, etc)?

Comment: I updated the post to show field value types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine and (&&) and or (||) operators, like this:

```
if(objQuote.records.SYS_Account_Credit_Application__c !== 'No' &&
    (objQuote.records.CAA_Agreement__c === null || objQuote.records.SYS_CAA_Active_Check__c !== 'Active')) {
```

Note here that you can apply De Morgan's Laws of Boolean Operations: NOT A OR NOT B can be expressed as NOT (A AND B).

```
if(objQuote.records.SYS_Account_Credit_Application__c !== 'No' &&
    !(objQuote.records.CAA_Agreement__c !== null && objQuote.records.SYS_CAA_Active_Check__c == 'Active')) {
```

Comment: sfdcfox, that seems to have did the trick! thanks.